# Using FMOD in C++ to create and playback sounds in realtime. (UE4)

Tags: c++, audio, unreal-engine4, fmod

Looking through all the API documentation, I can see how one could create procedural audio, but once an audio file is created, I want it to play on an object, but from I can tell, I believe I need it to play using the function calls PlayEventAtLocation in the UE4 plugin, which means I need to get the sound into an event.

I used to have my setup in Unity 4.x. I want to dynamically construct a wav file in game and play it back. The idea was to have silent audio all over the map that would loop, but play muted. The player when in range would capture audio from this muted audio source at their discretion.

The idea is that you have wav file that plays in game and at any given time I can start grabbing data from where the buffer is at currently until I decide to stop. I take all the data that I created in this new buffer and create a new wav file with it.

Example, like a 20 second file, but I would grab the a 7 second audio clip starting 5 seconds in. So my new audio file would be from 5 to 12. I would think you could do similar things in FMOD because I’ve looked at the recording examples and gapless playback examples, etc. and it does seem to have that same functionality and access to seek the files.

Now I need to migrate this new file that will made in game to something UE4 would use. In FMOD, looking through the .h and .cpp files in the plugin files, I see accept Fmod events only to attach to a UObject. Since I've not made an event in FMOD Studio, I can't use these. What is the sound that createSound makes? is it a wav? and fsb? I just a have a sound, and don't know what format it is.

I can’t use designer to make this sound because its dependent on the player at any given time during play.

In Unity, what I did was access the buffer of an audio file, pull data from the buffer for any given time, and place in a new buffer that I then turned into a file. While pulling data, I would check buffer size and frequency of sound files to make sure I had a gapless playback. (Not perfect, but pretty darn close), I’d use the audio functions in Unity to convert my array of data into a useable audioclip and run it through a sound emitter. It was pretty nice. Because I would keep the original wav file muted, but looping. So the player never knew what they captured. It was really nice.

Since UE4 doesn’t allow access to uncompressed PCM data, I can't do this low level data manipulation in UE4. I had to use FMOD, but its proving to be just as difficult because either its not documented, or lacks the functionality I want. I need help please.

If the data that is created in createsound is just normal pcm wav file data, then I can use a standard AudioComponent, and just save it to a file, and pull it in from UE4. If it is, then I need to turn it into an event so I can use FMODPlayEventAttached from the FMOD plugin library.

I've made a few other posts in various locations that have all been silent. Any comment would be appreciated. I know I've been reading a lot of documentation these last few days on FMOD, but I still may have missed something if people want to point me in a better direction, or if you have something to add, feel free.

Thanks all. I hope I was descriptive enough.

Comment: You are certainly deceptive. But I honestly can't work out what you are actually asking.

Comment: My apologies. I tried to be a descriptive as possible.

What I'm asking how do I create a sound in FMOD API without using the studio and be able to attach these sounds to UObjects in UE4